# Display image(BLOB) from mysql database to tkinter window

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

My database contains an image(BLOB) named LOGO. I want to display the image on python TkInter window

```
 import Tkinter
    window= Tk()
    db= MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","anup","NursecallDB")
    cursor=db.cursor()
    sql= "SELECT LOGO FROM SYSTEMDETAILS"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    logo=cursor.fetchone()
    img =PhotoImage(logo)
    panel = Tkinter.Label(window, image = img)
    panel.grid(row=0,rowspan=5,columnspan=2)
    window.mainloop()
```

when I am running this program it shows error at

```
panel = Tkinter.Label(window, image = img)
TypeError:_str_returned non-string(type tuple)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upload the image to a folder and insert the path into database. If logo is the path of the image. then program will work.

Answer (score 0):

PhotoImage take a string into argument which is the filename of the image you want to load or y Python image object. It cannot take blob as an argument. What you need is to load the image from a buffer (see the method here http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) and then pass the image to the PhotoImage constructor

Comment: <?php
    if( $_FILES['image']['name'] != "" )
    {
       copy( $_FILES['image']['name'], "/home/pi/image" ) or 
               die( "Could not copy file!");
    }    else
{
    die("No file specified!");
}
?> I have a RPI server and i am writing the above code to save the uploaded image.it shows could not copy file.

Answer (score 0):

If you, like me, don't want to pass the image through disk this is what the code looks like for python3 (following DARK_DUCK suggestion):

```
    from io import BytesIO
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk

    ...

    logo=cursor.fetchone()

    img = Image.open(BytesIO(logo))    
    phimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    panel = Tkinter.Label(window, image = phimg)
    panel.grid(row=0,rowspan=5,columnspan=2)
```

I think that for python 2.7 you'll have to use StringIO instead of BytesIO. See:
[Python PIL reading PNG from STDIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694230/python-pil-reading-png-from-stdin)